# How do I determine what packages require a certain library?

Tags: package-management, libraries

I currently have a bunch of KDE libraries installed on my computer, and I want to find out what packages I have installed that require them.  Does any one know a quick way to do this?

I'd prefer a command line solution, but a GUI one is fine as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Command line solution:

```
apt-cache --installed rdepends $pkg_name
```

Comment: This will show ALL the packages, not just the installed ones.

Comment: @arrange: you're right, I corrected my command line

Answer (score 1):

GUI solution:

1. Open Synaptic: System->Administration->Package Manager Synaptic
2. Find the desired library package using the search tool in the upper left corner
3. Right-click on a package, choose Properties (exact name may differ, I use a localized Ubuntu)
4. Go to tab Dependencies
5. Choose "Depending on that package" in the upper part of the tab
6. The requested list should appear.

Answer (score 1):

The brutish simple way:

```
sudo apt-get remove libkdewhatever
```

that will tell you what other applications will be removed, and ask if you want to continue.  If you want to keep them, cancel the removal.  If you don't want those apps, continue.

Comment: I suggest to add the `--simulate` option, so that you can also drop the `sudo`.

Comment: Good idea.  On the other hand if you think you probably do want to remove it, shoot first.